# Generate a .zip file using Forge Design Automation

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

I'm working on a web site using Forge Design Automation for AutoCAD, and I'd like to have a .zip file returned.  Does the .zip file have to go back to a URL (folder) located in site, or can it be downloaded directly to my view (MVC) through the controller?  And, if it can come back to the view, how do provide arguments to my workitem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The  Design Automation will want to PUT/POST the resulting zip file somewhere. So you must supply a resource (URL) that can be operated on by one of those verbs. 
Your website then can offer up the same resource to download to your clients. Clients cannot download directly from Design Automation as there's no HTTP resource that they could GET.

Comment: Well, shozbot.  I thought that was probably true, as I hadn't seen any examples of that.  Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

We can take advantage of the Forge OSS signed resource with read/write permission, so that Design Automation API will put the file to the Forge OSS bucket, and we can use the sample link to download the file. Please check my sample here. Although it's a Revit sample, the signed resource part can be applied to Design Automation API for AutoCAD, too.

- https://github.com/yiskang/forge-revit-fbx-export-bim360/blob/master/routes/da4revit.js#L92
- https://github.com/yiskang/forge-revit-fbx-export-bim360/blob/master/routes/da4revit.js#L216
- https://github.com/yiskang/forge-revit-fbx-export-bim360/blob/master/public/js/ForgeDesignAutomation.js#L58
- https://github.com/yiskang/forge-revit-fbx-export-bim360/blob/master/public/js/ForgeDesignAutomation.js#L220

Comment: Thank you Eason.  I will certainly look into that.

Comment: Okay, I’m down to this:

I have a file that's getting uploaded, and my APP package is executing, but I’m having trouble getting it back to my web site.

I have a function that sends for a basic authentication request to my site.


I get a response with a static code of OK, but I don’t know how to incorporate into my WorkItem request.  I don't know if I use the response headers in the WI result argument or if I create another WI argument.

{ "result", new XrefTreeArgument() { Verb=Verb.Put, Url = OutputURL} }  Is this doable, or I do need to try something else?